# Is there a special word for orange clouds/sky we see at dusk?

Tags: word-choice

Like we have a silver lining for clouds, do we have a special name or phrase for clouds or sky that turns into this lovely orange/pink colour during dusk? Attaching a figure for reference. [image: sunset]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The English language, like every human language, is finite. It comes pre-loaded with lots of words that people through its history have needed, but some things that you might want to say do not have words yet. I think the appearance of the sky in your picture is one of these things. I don't know of a one-word expression for that sky.

This is where your own creativity and poetic genius come into play. You can combine the words we already have to express exactly what you want to say. Sometimes people even make up their own words, and if they are good ones, we all adopt them into our vocabularies.

Answer (score 1):

"The sunset" might be the easiest way to talk about this.

We could say "Come and look at the sunset" to mean the red clouds, not the actual setting sun. Or "The sunset on the coast of Croatia is famous for fiery red hues."

We sometimes just talk about a "red sky (at night)" which is said to be a "shepherd's delight, as it indicates dry weather coming.